# How to call value from override method java?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

**how can i get value from override method?**

This is my code and i tired to set url into `setValue(url)` but i couldn't get

```
String url =dlUri.toString(); this value

child("downloadurl").setValue(url);
```

[image]

```
public void upload(View view){

    UUID uuidImage = UUID.randomUUID();

    String imageName = "images/"+uuidImage+".jpg";

    final StorageReference storageReference = mStorageRef.child(imageName);

    storageReference.putFile(selected).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {



        @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {


            UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
            final String uuidString = uuid.toString();

            storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    Uri dlUri = uri;
                    String url =dlUri.toString();
                }
            });

            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            String userEmail = user.getEmail().toString();
            String userComment = commentText.getText().toString();


            myRef.child("Posts").child(uuidString).child("useremail").setValue(userEmail);
            myRef.child("Posts").child(uuidString).child("comment").setValue(userComment);
            myRef.child("Posts").child(uuidString).child("downloadurl").setValue(url);




            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Post Shared",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FeedActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getLocalizedMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `String url = dlUri.toString();` is not inside the scope where you want to access it. Why don't you just move all your code inside `onSuccess()`, since I assume that you need to wait for the value anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Declare `url` outside of `storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener()`. Before using, you should check if `url` is null or not

```
String url;
storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                Uri dlUri = uri;
                url =dlUri.toString();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to call storageReference.getDownloadUrl() again in onSsuccesslistener you candirectly get url as

> taskSnapshot.downloadUrl.toString()

refer below code.

```
storageReference.putFile(selected).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

    @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
              String url = taskSnapshot.downloadUrl.toString()
       } }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getLocalizedMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});

   }
```

Comment: This is wrong. Note that both `onSucces` methods are not equal in the question.

Comment: String url = taskSnapshot.downloadUrl.toString()                                                                         This usage has been removed.